# mac screensaver start event

Tags: c, objective-c, macos, events, screensaver

Is there an event fired when screensaver starts? Like for keychain locking:

```
OSStatus keychain_locked(SecKeychainEvent keychainEvent, SecKeychainCallbackInfo *info, void *context){...}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Finally found it — the solution is to use NSDistributedNotificationCenter and observe folowing events

- com.apple.screensaver.didstart
- com.apple.screensaver.willstop
- com.apple.screensaver.didstop
- com.apple.screenIsLocked
- com.apple.screenIsUnlocked

Like

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(screensaverStarted:)
   name:@"com.apple.screensaver.didstart"
   object:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

While there is no Carbon event for this, you *can* get notified when the current application changes, and then check to see if the new application is the screen saver process.

---

```
// Register the event handler for when applications change
{
    EventTypeSpec es;
    es.eventClass = kEventClassApplication;
    es.eventKind = kEventAppFrontSwitched;
    InstallApplicationEventHandler(&appChanged, 1, &es, NULL, NULL);
}

OSStatus appChanged(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef anEvent, void* userData)
{
    ProcessSerialNumber psn;    
    GetEventParameter(anEvent, kEventParamProcessID, typeProcessSerialNumber,
                      NULL, sizeof(psn), NULL, &psn);

    // Determine process name
    char procName[255];
    {
        ProcessInfoRec pInfo;
        Str255 procName255;
        FSRef ref;

        pInfo.processInfoLength = sizeof(ProcessInfoRec);
        pInfo.processName = procName255;
        pInfo.processAppRef = &ref;
        GetProcessInformation(&psn, &pInfo);

        const unsigned int size = (unsigned int)procName255[0];
        memcpy(procName, procName255 + 1, size);
        procName[size] = '\0';
    }

    if(strcmp(procName, "ScreenSaverEngine") == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found %s\n", procName);
    }

    return noErr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly an answer to the question, but I spent a lot of time looking in vain for a list of the notifications posted by macOS, so I wanted to post some code I wrote for notification discovery.

The code simply signs up to listen to *all* notifications, and prints some info for each as it comes in.

```
import Foundation

let distCenter = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter()
if distCenter == nil {
    exit(1)
}

CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(distCenter, nil, { (center, observer, name, object, userInfo) -> Void in
        print("Event occurred: \(name)  User info: \(userInfo)")
    }, nil, nil, .DeliverImmediately)

CFRunLoopRun()
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the list of events you found using this?